# WebWorker HTML5 y setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando entender el funcionamiento de los Web Workers.
He utilizado el ejemplo de este tutorial: [1](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)

y puedo enternder el funcionamiento. Siguiendo la lógica del código, entiendo que el script de la página principal HTML, llama a la función que está en la carpeta demo_workers.js. Esta a su vez, envia el valor de i a la página principal. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Lo que pretendo hacer es que el WebWorker, al pulsar un botón, llame a una función, que no devuelve nada a la página principal, pero que active un temporizador para ejecutar una función que envía mensajes PUSH. Este es el código:
Web Worker:

```
<!-- PRUEBA WEB WORKER-->

<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not
```

support Web Workers.

```
<script>
var w;

function startWorker() {
if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
        w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
    }
    //¿¿¿¿¿AQUI VA EL CODIGO QUE ME FALTA.???????
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does 
not support Web Workers...";
}
}

function stopWorker() { 
w.terminate();
w = undefined;
}
```

En un archivo .js llamado demo_workers.js tengo las funciones que crean el aviso y la que lo activa con un retardo calculado en función de un tiempo recibido de una base de datos.

CODIGO:

```
//Notificaciones PUSH
var aviso="prueba";
function notificacion(){

//verificar si el navegador soporta notificaciones
if(!("Notification" in window)){
    alert("Tu navegador no soporta notificaciones");
}else if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
    //Lanzar notificacion
    var notification=new Notification(aviso);
}else if(Notification.permission!=="denied"){
    Notification.requestPermission(function(permission){
    if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
       var notificacion=new Notification(aviso);
    }
    });
  }
}


function getTemporizadores(){


$.ajax({

    url: "tiempoPasoAvisos.php",
    type:"GET",  
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        for (var parada in data){
            //data es un string en formato HH:MM:SS
            var valor=data[parada].split(":");
            var milisegundos=(valor[0]*3600000)+(valor[1]*600000)+ 
     (valor[2]*1000);
            setTimeout("notificacion()",milisegundos);
        }
        aviso=parada;  
      }
    });


 }
 getTemporizadores();
```

Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta programación web y tengo bastantes carencias. Agradecería sencillez en las respuestas por favor.
Gracias.

Quiero aclarar que el código funciona sin utilizar el web Worker pero el problema es que tengo entendido que la funcion SetTimeout no funciona en navegadores de dispositivos móviles y que la solución pasa por usar un WebWorker.

Comment: La consola de errores me dice esto: VM11 demo_workers.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at getTemporizadores (VM11 demo_workers.js:37)
    at VM11 demo_workers.js:62.            Es como si no aceptara la petición AJax

Comment: ¿Has incluido jQuery en el proyecto? Ese $ es el objeto que expone jQuery para utilizar sus funciones.

Comment: con el web worker no haras llamados directos a su codigo, solo puedes enviar /escuchar mensajes.

Comment: @ordago Si que lo tengo añadido.